selenium.InvalidArgumentException: The action id 'finger' has one one or more duplicates
I'm trying to perform a Swip action using the W3C actions, but while constructing my swipe when I'm going to perform the action is saying that the action id 'finger' has one or more duplicates.
fun swipe(
        direction: SwipeDirection,
        edgeOffset: Point = Point(200, 200),
    ) {
        val dimension = driver.manage().window().size
        val startPoint: Point
        val endPoint: Point

        when (direction) {
            SwipeDirection.Up -> {
                startPoint = Point(dimension.width / 2, dimension.height - edgeOffset.y)
                endPoint = Point(dimension.width / 2, edgeOffset.y)
            }

            SwipeDirection.Down -> {
                startPoint = Point(dimension.width / 2, edgeOffset.y)
                endPoint = Point(dimension.width / 2, dimension.height - edgeOffset.y)
            }

            SwipeDirection.Right -> {
                startPoint = Point(edgeOffset.x, dimension.height / 2)
                endPoint = Point(dimension.width - edgeOffset.x, dimension.height / 2)
            }

            SwipeDirection.Left -> {
                startPoint = Point(dimension.width - edgeOffset.x, dimension.height / 2)
                endPoint = Point(edgeOffset.x, dimension.height / 2)
            }
        }

        swipe(startPoint, endPoint)
    }

 fun swipe(
        start: Point,
        end: Point,
    ) {
        moveByOffset(start.x, start.y)
        clickAndHold()
        pause(Timeouts.SHORT_TOUCH)
        moveByOffset(end.x, end.y)
        release()
        perform()
    }

The following log appears to me:

org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: The action id 'finger' has one one or more duplicates Build info: version: '4.19.0', revision: '5f9cec8963' System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '14.3', java.version: '17.0.9' Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver Command: [e71a8d51-6b6d-4372-b73e-b427cb0f8cc9, actions {actions=[org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Sequence@f7985c6, org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Sequence@2768d45e]}] Capabilities {appium:app: /Users/perrystreet/Document..., appium:appPackage: com.appspot.scruffapp, appium:appWaitForLaunch: false, appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:clearDeviceLogsOnStart: true, appium:databaseEnabled: false, appium:desired: {app: /Users/perrystreet/Document..., appWaitForLaunch: false, automationName: UIAutomator2, clearDeviceLogsOnStart: true, mjpegServerPort: 56346, nativeWebScreenshot: true, platformName: ANDROID}, appium:deviceApiLevel: 34, appium:deviceManufacturer: Google, appium:deviceModel: sdk_gphone64_arm64, appium:deviceName: emulator-5556, appium:deviceScreenDensity: 420, appium:deviceScreenSize: 1080x2400, appium:deviceUDID: emulator-5556, appium:javascriptEnabled: true, appium:locationContextEnabled: false, appium:mjpegServerPort: 56346, appium:nativeWebScreenshot: true, appium:networkConnectionEnabled: true, appium:pixelRatio: 2.625, appium:platformVersion: 14, appium:statBarHeight: 128, appium:takesScreenshot: true, appium:viewportRect: {height: 2272, left: 0, top: 128, width: 1080}, appium:warnings: {}, appium:webStorageEnabled: false, platformName: ANDROID} Session ID: e71a8d51-6b6d-4372-b73e-b427cb0f8cc9 at java.base@17.0.9/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at java.base@17.0.9/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at java.base@17.0.9/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at java.base@17.0.9/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Unknown Source) at java.base@17.0.9/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodec.decode(ErrorCodec.java:167) at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:138) at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:50) at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:190) at app//io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:237) at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:518) at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.perform(RemoteWebDriver.java:604) at app//org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions$BuiltAction.perform(Actions.java:603) at app//org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.perform(Actions.java:568) at app//support.Actions.swipe(Actions.kt:86)

I tried using different ways of W3C actions but none of then come with solution.
